# Select menu options don't stick to parent element when scrolling through an inner element

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, ng-zorro-antd

When scrolling through an inner element the select options menu does not scroll along with the page instead, it sticks in the same position

[Basic HTML Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiUy2.jpg)

[When Scrolling the inner div element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmfvl.jpg)

Here is the code for the app.component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

```css
.wide{
  width: 200px;
}

body{
  height: 2000px;
}

.container{
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nz-select class="wide">
    <nz-option
      class="wide"
      *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
      [nzLabel]="item"
    ></nz-option>
  </nz-select>
  <p>
    Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Some Text Some
    Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
    Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some
    Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
    Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Some Text Some
    Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
    Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text
    Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some
    TextSome Text Text Some Text Some Text Some TextSome Text Text Some Text
    Some Text Some TextSome Text
  </p>
</div>
```

How do I make the options menu stick to its parent element?

I want the options menu to stay connected to it's parent select element when scrolling

Comment: Please give more context and a [mcve]. Also, the CDK being bound to the body is expected, that's how overlays work.

Comment: thanks for the tip, are the edits satisfactory?

Comment: Not at all. Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I've created a work around using (scroll)

app.component.html -

```
<div class="inner-content" (scroll)="SetupOnScroll($event,routerOutletContainer)" #routerOutletContainer>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.ts -

```
SetupOnScroll(event:any,routerOutletContainer:any){
  let overlaypanes:any = document.getElementsByClassName("cdk-overlay-pane");
  let amountScrolled = this.lastScrollTop - routerOutletContainer.scrollTop;
  this.lastScrollTop = routerOutletContainer.scrollTop;
  if(overlaypanes.length > 0){
    for (let index = 0; index < overlaypanes.length; index++) {
      const overlaypane = overlaypanes[index];
      const paneTop = overlaypane.style.top;
      const paneBottom = overlaypane.style.bottom;
      if(paneTop != 0){
        overlaypane.style.top = Number(paneTop.replace("px", "")) + amountScrolled +"px";
      }
      if(paneBottom != 0){
        overlaypane.style.bottom = Number(paneBottom.replace("px", "")) + (amountScrolled * -1) +"px";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would update the top or bottom of the currently opened cdk-overlay-pane according to the scroll value